# Updating BlueZ 5.23 => 5.36

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth

I am running `Linux raspberrypi 4.1.13+ #826 PREEMPT Fri Nov 13 20:13:22 GMT 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux` on my Raspberry Pi Model B.

The RPi comes preinstalled with BlueZ v5.23, which is horribly outdated and buggy. I hoped to install the newer BlueZ v5.36, so I checked out their repo. I disabled `systemd` in the configure process and let it `make`. 
But even after a successful `sudo make install` and multiple reboots, `bluetoothd -v` still returns `5.23`.

Does anybody have an idea why this could be and how to update BlueZ?

Comment: What is the output of: which bluetoothd? did you uninstall the previous version? Did you stop the old version from starting? Is their an entry in /etc/alternatives? If so what does it point to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BlueZ 5.43 is available in the [Stretch repositories](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/bluez), but Jessie only comes with [version 5.23](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/bluez).

I'd try the following to get the more recent version:
Add the stretch sources to your `sources.list` and at the same time tell APT to (still) default to jessie. You'd do the former by copy/paste the jessie line and in the copy change `jessie` to `stretch`. You'd do the latter by creating a file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/40defaultrelease` with the following contents:

```
APT::Default-Release "jessie";
```

Then do `apt-get update` to let APT know of the new packages and versions.
To install `bluez` from stretch/testing, do the following: `apt-get install bluez -t stretch`. This will install `bluez` and its dependencies from `stretch`.
This way you get a nicely packed Debian/Raspbian package, but at the version you want.
Because of the `APT::Default-Release "jessie"` you'd still install/upgrade package from `jessie` by default and would only get `stretch` package when you explicitly request them (with '-t').

There's also a small variation to that and that is `apt-get install bluez/stretch` and this will only install the `bluez` package itself from `stretch`, but the rest from `jessie`. This may be a 'cleaner' variant as will only install that one package from `stretch`. OTOH it may cause an installation problem if it can't satisfy it's dependencies from `jessie`.
In that case I suggest to do it with aptitude like this: `aptitude install bluez/stretch`.
The dependency resolver of `aptitude` is more powerful then `apt-get`'s and will likely find a solution to it. It may come up with 1 (or more) 'bogus' suggestions, but just say 'n' then and let it calculate a new solution till you find one that is appropriate.

Comment: Try comparing the timestamp of the existing /usr/sbin/bluetoothd with the bluez-5.36/src/bluetoothd after the make. It could also be that Makefile does not have a rule to install bluetoothd. In which case move the original blueoothd to a .org and copy the src/bluetoothd into /usr/sbin and try to restart the daemon.

Comment: @VittalNBadithe I think you want to add your comment to the question, not this answer ;-)

Comment: This approach works fine to install BlueZ 5.36.  The bad news is that after installing this with the latest pi kernel you get an error when pairing "Bluetooth: SMP security requested but not available".  If anybody knows how to fix this short of compiling a new Kernel I would like to hear it.

Comment: 5.39 appears to fix the issue with pairing and SMP security.  I would recommend against doing the above method and instead just install 5.39 from source.

Answer (score 3):

This was pre Jessie but I logged the following steps in March

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git 
cd bluez

sudo apt-get install autoconf make automake cmake libtool libglib2.0 libdbus-1-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev 
libtoolize --force
```

then

```
aclocal 
autoheader 
automake --force-missing --add-missing 
autoconf
./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-experimental --with-systemdsystemunitdir=/lib/systemd/system --with-systemduserunitdir=/usr/lib/systemd
make
```

from my blog http://www.jumpstation.co.uk/flog/Mar2015.html#p090320152120

Comment: there are some spaces in your `apt-get install` line which shouldn't be there. As it's only 2 characters, I (apparently) couldn't edit it myself.

Comment: @DiederikdeHaas well spotted, fixed

Comment: There are a few things that don't work [I am a Linux noob, so forgive me if they are obvious]. First `--force` isn't allowed, secondly it can't locate `libtoolize`

Comment: And automake fails with `error: required file './ltmain.sh' not found`

Comment: @bluewhile sorry the libtoolize --force was supposed to be on its own line.