# How to upgrade bluez to 5.37

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, apt

I've got a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Jessie installed.

I am trying to get flic buttons working with my pi (based on [this](https://github.com/50ButtonsEach/fliclib-linux-dist) github project).

To get this to work I need Bluez 5.37. When I update I don't get a version as new as that.

I have been able to download 5.37, build it and get it running but each time I restart my pi I have to stop the original bluez and start the new version that is installed in a different location.

How do I replace the system version with 5.37 and get it to run when the system reboots.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating BlueZ 5.23 => 5.36](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39254/updating-bluez-5-23-5-36)